# Teamcity10 + .Net 4.6.1 = wrong MSBuild path

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

After installation .Net 4.6.1 on TeamCity BuildAgents machine I have error in buildstep where I have to use MSBuild 2015.

Error say:

`Unable to find MSBuild at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe\MSBuild.exe, please check MSBuild environment variable to target to Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0/3.5/4.0 or Mono installation directory`

Where I can define again path of MSBuild?
When I go to `Agents >> Agent Parameters >> Environment Variables`  I have parameter like that:
`msbuild     C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

Uninstall .nets (4.5.1,4.5.2,4.6.1) ane MSbuild and MSbuild Tools did not work. 
Also try setup new agent but at the end I had the same problem.

Comment: Try to change msbuild version in build configuration.

Comment: Already tried that option.

Comment: Already tried that option. Once it worked (I had change version from 2015:14 for 2015:none), now I have problem on every versions combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.
I have edited: `buildAgent.properties`

At the end of file I just add: env.msbuild=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin

Now in Agent Properties is only path without EXE file in.